# Feynman lectures and apparent area of a nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering-cross-section

In paragraph 5.7 of [this](https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_152403379736613&key=6afc78eea2339e9c047ab6748b0d37e7&libId=jg4qclru010009we000DAma3pb12e4avz&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.physicsforums.com%2Fthreads%2Ffeynman-apparent-area-of-a-nucleus.944747%2F&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu%2FI_05.html&title=Feynman%20Apparent%20area%20of%20a%20nucleus%20%7C%20Physics%20Forums&txt=this) lecture, Feynman explains how to calculate the apparent area of the nucleus, in a sheet of unspecified material.

In the note Feynman says:

> "This equation is right only if the area covered by the nuclei is a small fraction of the total, i.e., if $\frac{n1-n2}{n1}$ is much less than 1. Otherwise we must make a correction for the fact that some nuclei will be partly obscured by the nuclei in front of them"

Do you have any idea how to apply this correction factor to the previous formula?

Comment: The lecture to which you refer (FLP Volume I, chapter 5) is by Matthew Sands, not Richard Feynman. Feynman was out of town that week. Every appearance of the name "Feynman" in your question and the answer below should be replaced by "Sands."

Editor, The Feynman Lectures on Physics New Millennium Edition

Comment: Hi @Michael. Can you please [suggest edits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to the question (and answer, now that I see your comment there) that would refer to the work appropriately?

Comment: Also @MichaelA.Gottlieb, I don't see any reference on the linked page to whether that particular lecture was delivered by (or prepared by) Feynman or Leighton or Sands. If you think that Leighton and Sands deserve more credit for their contributions to FLP, a future edition might make it easier for the casual reader to identify which authors are responsible for which sections. One approach for the online version would be to include a "cite this as" sentence on each page, like Weisstein has done for many years at his MathWorld.

Comment: Hi, Rob. I've already suggested edits. Regarding a reference, Feynman says in his Preface that Sands gave the 5th and 6th lectures when he was out of town. Regarding attribution: Leighton and Sands are co-authors of FLP because they contributed original material throughout. However, other than the two lectures given by Sands, it's difficult to make specific attributions. Sands' and Leighton's original material is well-dispersed and seamlessly interwoven with Feynman's material, which unfortunately leads most people to think the book has only one author.

Comment: @MichaelA.Gottlieb Actually I meant something a little different: you should have a link under the question that says "edit" or "improve this question." Click that link and you can make the citation read how you think it should read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "apparent area" is called the [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)), usually denoted with a sigma, $\sigma$.

Suppose (as Feynman et al. do) that you're interested in the probability that scattering from a nucleus removes a particle from the beam.  If the thickness $\ell$ of your target is small enough that the overlap between nuclei is negligible, and the number density of the target nuclei is $n$ nuclei per unit volume, then the probability that a particle from your beam makes it through undeflected is

$$
p_\text{thin} = 1 - n\sigma\ell.
$$

If your target has large thickness $L$ so that this approximation doesn't apply, you can divide it up into many thin targets; the probability of transmitting through all the layers is the product of the probabilities of making it through each layer.  That is,

\begin{align}
p_\text{thick} &= \prod_\text{all layers} p_\text{layer}
= \left( 1 - \frac{n\sigma L}N \right)^N,
\end{align}

if you divide the target into $N$ thin layers.
The continuum result is

\begin{align}
\lim_{\text{smooth}} p_\text{thick} &= \lim_{N\to\infty} (p_\text{thin})^N
= e^{-n\sigma L}
\end{align}

The transmission through a thick target is exponential in the length of the target.